# What is wrong with the syntax near 'id'?

Tags: mysql

```
  CREATE TABLE post(
   'id' int UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
   'title' VARCHAR(100),
   'content' VARCHAR(5000),
   'writer' VARCHAR(100),
   'updated_at' TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   'created_at' DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY(id)
  );
```

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''id' int UNSIGNED AUTO INCREMENT, 'title' VARCHAR(100), 'content' VARCHAR(5000' at line 2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Field names need to be wrapped in backtics - quotes will cause an error.

So,

```
`id` int UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
`title` VARCHAR(100),
```

etc.

Comment: +1 Or leave the backtics out completely. They hurt my eyes when they're unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks mate I accidently clicked -1. Don't mind it. Your answer is great! It worked!

Comment: I will +1 it. Just give me some time.

Comment: @isuru you're welcome. Don't worry, I'm not seeing a -1, I don't think it applied.

Comment: @isurumadusanka Be sure to accept the answer as well by clicking on the outlined check mark next to it.